# Grails- <g:formRemote> send a request though the form is not Valid

Tags: forms, grails, subnet

I use   in my template:

```
 <g:formRemote  id="accountInfoForm" name="updateInfo" url='[controller:"settings", action: "updateProfile"]' onSuccess="triggerReload()" update="personal-info" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

I have in my form the following submitButton:

```
<g:submitButton type="submit" class="update-button" name="Update" id="updateInfo"></g:submitButton>
```

When I click on the submitButton a request to the URL happens though the form is not valid (The errors are displayed)

Of course that the form is not updated because the is an error in the post request. But the request shouldn't be sent at all if the form is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The standard FormRemote Tag doesn't validate the Form, the Validation is made on the Application Side, that's why you got the Error back.

To send the Form to the URL only when the form is valid you have to use an Client Side Validation like [this](http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/)

Comment: I also tried  <g:formRemote  class="formInfo" name="updateInfo" url='[controller:"settings", action: "updateProfile"]'  before="validateForm()"  update="personalInformation" onSuccess="triggerReload()" accept-charset="utf-8"> . validateForm() implement the client validation. But for some reason the function of onSuccess isn't called

Comment: The onSuccess Function is only called if the response return HTTP Code 200. If another HTTP Code returned the onFailure Function is called. After onSucces or onFailure the onComplete Function is called. I think in your Case you need to call triggerReload in the onComplete Function, because you want to reload the form every time, doesn't matter what HTTP Code  returned.